# Problems with prepare application to release - integrate dotfuscater protection Xamarin, Visual Studio 2017, android

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, dotfuscator

I prepare my application to release ( android ) , during perform integration dotfuscator , described in

https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html
On build of android project receive following error

> PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets(251,9): error MSB4184: The
>   expression """.TargetName" cannot be evaluated. Method
>   'System.String.TargetName' not found.

I get the file PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets as is. Should it be changed after download ?

I use Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017.

Thanks,
Anna

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer*: I work for PreEmptive Solutions on the Dotfuscator team, and am answering in that capacity.

**Update**: This issue has been corrected in version 1.3.0 of the file, available [here](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html#setup-targets).
The original answer follows.

This is an error in the `PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets` file.
We've filed an issue internally, but as a workaround for today, you can edit line 251 of that file to replace this:

```
<Destination>%(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath.Culture)\$(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath.TargetName).resources.dll</Destination>
```

with this:

```
<Destination>%(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath.Culture)\$(TargetName).resources.dll</Destination>
```

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.