# Code is not obfuscating in Xamarin.Forms using dotfuscator

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotfuscator

I have followed the steps provided on https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_xamarin.html#setup-targets

When I build the app, it gives below error.

**The expression """.TargetName" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.TargetName' not found.**

Then I edited line 251 of that file to replace this:

```
<Destination>%(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath.Culture)\$(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath.TargetName).resources.dll</Destination>
```

with this:

```
<Destination>%(IntermediateSatelliteAssembliesWithTargetPath.Culture)\$(TargetName).resources.dll</Destination>
```

Ref: 
[Problems with prepare application to release - integrate dotfuscater protection Xamarin, Visual Studio 2017, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568995/problems-with-prepare-application-to-release-integrate-dotfuscater-protection)

But after doing all the steps, when I try to re-engineer the app.dll file, it is not obfuscating.

Comment: Just to be clear, the build from Visual Studio succeeds? If so, the `App.dll` may be getting obfuscated, just to a weaker degree by default. You might want to turn off [Library Mode](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/5.30/obfuscation_overview.html#pctoc-library-mode). Also, if you're using the free Community Edition, note that it only renames classes/methods/etc., it doesn't modify the structure of code in the methods like Professional Edition does with its Control Flow obfuscation. (I work for the Dotfuscator team).

Comment: @JoeSewell Thanks for your feedback. Actually, I have set dotfuscator.exe in Dotfuscator CLI path instead of dotfuscatorCLI.exe.